# Change paper size in journal document class

Tags: document-classes, paper-size, journal

I'm using [this journal's style files](http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/pdf/gji-latex.zip) and I can see that the `.cls` file defines paper size as `a4paper` in the following line:

```
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,twoside,final}
```

However, compiling any document with this class uses a US letter paper, which crops the bottom. I can't even use `a4paper` as an option. What should I change to get A4 sizing?

If you want an MWE, just try recompiling the `gjilguid2e.tex` that is present in the zip file. The included PDF file is A4, but upon recompiling, it switches to US letter for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `gji` does not provide `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. Also the output driver (pdfTeX, dvips, …) is not notified about the paper dimensions (LaTeX does not do this job).
The former can be done manually, the latter can be done by package `geometry`. Option `pass` is used to avoid changing the current page layout settings.

```
\documentclass{gji}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}% fixed.
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. A small  typo — 207 should be 297, but that's not essential to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, that was a test setting that I had forgotten to revert.